# HighStock not Overlapping data

Tags: highcharts

Currently i´m registering every 10 seconds if my services are accessable via netcast command.

> nc -zvvw 10 ip port

A success is registered as a 1, otherwise a 0. The format is something like this:

> date;server1;server2;serverN+1

But, it seems like Highcharts put some decimal data that i dont know where are from. And the data is not overlapping at all. (The 1 or the 0) Or at least two series than i'm aware of.

Here is an example about i'm trying to explain if my spanish level is not good enough

http://jsbin.com/overlaping/3/

can anybody help me please.

Edit 1:
The data is from a json source, it's looks like this:

> var data = {"titulos":["fecha","server1","server2","server3","server4","server5"],"detalles":[[1389495600000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495600000,1,1,1,1,1]]}

But for an entire day, every ten seconds.

Edit 2:
Wergeld noticed that i having the same timestamp (on ms) for more than a row of data. That was 'cause i was parsing the date without seconds.

> SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

But i added the seconds and it is given me different dates for every row (as i should expect), but the problems persist.

The data now looks like this:

> {"titulos":["fecha","yelcho","villarica","coya","cunco","culenar"],"detalles":[[1389495606000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495616000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495627000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495637000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495647000,1,1,1,1,1],[1389495657000,1,1,1,1,1]]}

Edit 3:
it seems to be some kind of behaviour at a large amount of data and trying to display all. If i zoom it enough, it display correctly. There is a way to display it properly even at full zoom out?

Edit 4:
I ended using this code to solve my problem. Thanks to Pawel Fus for his help.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true,
            approximation: 'open'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: What does your series.data look like?

Comment: I edited the question to give a example. But the problems seems to appear only in a large amount of data.

Comment: Most likely cause is that for the same resolution time stamp you are getting back multiple responses - as you see in your to data elements. They are both for the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `dataGrouping`, you can disable it.

However, it may be very slow to display 10 000points (with markers) on a chart width width 1 000px (10 points on a 1 pixel).

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).

Comment: Thanks. That worked! But now i'm concerned about the performance as you suggested. Is there any advice about it?

Comment: Do grouping on a server side - when you show all data. When user zooms in, call AJAX with certain points. See [this article](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts).